# mysqldump doesn't run correctly

Tags: php, backup, xampp, mysql

I write some code with PHP to backup database.

Here my code:

```
exec("mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u root test > mydb.sql");
```

But I get 0-byte in my file (mydb.sql). I also run with passthru(), system(), but it still gets 0-byte.

I try to use command. It works.

I use the lastest XAMPP for my localhost.

So, how can I do to make it works correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely a permissions issue, or the fact you're not passing a password. To see errors,  route STDERR to STDOUT using `2>&1`

```
exec("mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u root test > mydb.sql 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

This will show you the errors you'd normally see on the command line.

Comment: My problem is similar to that of OP but in my case, there is no output file (not even empty one) on running through PHP. The script on my local server finishes instantly, so it does not look like to be a timeout issue either. `print_r($output);` gives an empty array - `Array()`. My command is `$command = "/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u ".$_POST['db_user']." ".$_POST['db_name']." > /root/Desktop/downloaded.sql 2>&1";` and the very same command produces correct result in command line (a 1.7 MB file). PHP is not running in safe mode, `exec()` is not disabled and I am clueless. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Oh I fixed it. It was permission issue. The output location has to be inside `/opt/lampp/htdocs`. But there should have been some error display.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely mysqldump is not in PHP/Apache's path. That will cause the shell to spit out a "command not found" error on STDERR, and no output on STDOUT (which you redirect to a file and ends up with 0 length).

Try adding the full path to mysqldump (`c:\mysql\bin\mysqldump` or whatever) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the password with no space after the -p option and the same for the username goes directly after -u

exec("mysqldump --opt -h localhost -uUSER -pPASSWORD DBNAME > mydb.sql");

i anther problem on a shared host it turned out i have to use the host username and password not the database username and password

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname   = "test";

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dbname . "_" .date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").".sql"));

$command = "C:\AppServ\MySQL\bin\mysqldump --add-drop-table --host=$hostname --   user=$username --password=$password ".$dbname;

system($command);
```

Comment: why do you answered two times?

Comment: is because I was not able to send, then ended up sending twice and still could not delete!

Comment: Which part of this is supposed to be solving the problem?

Comment: the code above is just one more way of doing, the only solution to solve the problem and hire a dedicated server, because not every hosting plan allows the use of functions like 'system' and 'exec'

Answer (score 0):

commands such as exec () and system () do not work on all servers, only local servers and dedicated servers, if you host a server will have to see whether your hosting plan allows access to exec (command) and system () if you will not allow to hire another plan.

Comment: This is not likely to be the explanation. The fact that the output file is being created (although empty) means that `exec` is running the command.